# Docker MGT Development Environment and Mailbag

Tags: magento, docker

I have installed Magento 1.9.0.1 on docker MGT development environment with 2 docker containers. The idea is for all e-mails produced by the magento container are to be caught by the mailhog container smtp.

```
    docker run -d -p 8025:8025 -p 1025:1025 --name smtp mailhog/mailhog 
    docker run -d --net=bridge --restart=always --privileged -h mgt-dev-56 --link smtp --name mgt-dev-56 -it -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 22:22 -p 3306:3306 -p 3333:3333 mgtcommerce/mgt-development-environment-5.6
```

I have named the mailhog container **smtp** and have linked it via the **--link smtp** parameter on the mgt-dev-56 container. Both the container applications work via their respective URLs magento1.dev and 127.0.0.1:8025. However I can not get the smtp container to catch any the emails being generated from the mgt-dev-56 container.
I'm not sure if i need to configure postfix to point to a certain port or ip. I have noticed and confirmed that the there is network connectivity between containers mgt-dev-56 and smtp.

Has any one come across this issue before ? 
Do I need to modify the configurations on postfix ?

Here is the main.cf of mgt-dev-56 container

```
        root@mgt-dev-56:/etc/postfix# vi main.cf
        smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
        biff = no
        append_dot_mydomain = no
        readme_directory = no
        smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
        smtpd_use_tls=yes
        smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
        smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
        smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
        myhostname = mgt-dev-56
        myorigin = $myhostname
        alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
        alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
        mydestination = mgt-dev-56, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
        relayhost = 172.17.0.3:1025
        mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
        mailbox_size_limit = 0
        recipient_delimiter = +
        inet_interfaces = all
```

Here is are the env of mgt-dev-56 container, BTW 172.17.0.3 is the IP address for the smtp container.

```
        root@mgt-dev-56:/etc/postfix# env 
        SMTP_PORT_1025_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.3
        HOSTNAME=mgt-dev-56
        SMTP_PORT_8025_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.3:8025
        TERM=xterm
        SMTP_ENV_no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16
        SMTP_PORT_1025_TCP_PORT=1025
        SMTP_PORT_8025_TCP_PORT=8025
        SMTP_PORT_1025_TCP_PROTO=tcp
        SMTP_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.3:1025
        PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
        PWD=/etc/postfix
        SMTP_PORT_8025_TCP_PROTO=tcp
        SHLVL=1
        HOME=/root
        no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16
        SMTP_PORT_8025_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.3
        SMTP_NAME=/mgt-dev-56/smtp
        SMTP_PORT_1025_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.3:1025
        _=/usr/bin/env
        OLDPWD=/root/cloudpanel
```

Comment: Please post your solution as a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced the configuration parameter relayhost with actual ip and port number instead of using the environment variable SMTP_PORT_8025_TCP as main.cf and postfix does not like environment variables. MailHog now pickups the all e-mails created via line command and magento.